# C# .NET standard 1.6 with excessive dependencies in published application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying out Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core in what is my first attempt at C#/.NET in a few years (returning from Golang). I tried to create a small hello world style networking application that just listens and echos the input from tcp clients:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace TaskSockets
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5555);
            server.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient newClient = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync().Result;

                Task.Run(async () => {

                    StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(newClient.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
                    StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(newClient.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

                    Boolean bClientConnected = true;
                    String sData = null;

                    while (bClientConnected)
                    {
                        sData = await sReader.ReadLineAsync();

                        Console.WriteLine("Client: " + sData);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My project/build config looks like the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR" Version="1.1.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy" Version="1.1.0" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

After publishing the application (dotnet publish) I get a folder with the executable I need. The problem I encounter, however, is that the folder contains 205 files (mostly .NET related DLL files) and is more than 30 MB in size. This includes dll files with reference to .NET libraries I don't even use such as System.Xml and Linq.

Is there any way to reduce the number of files and size of the published application so that just what I need is included?

UPDATE:
Tried to re-create the project from scratch using the dotnet tool rather than visual studio:

> dotnet new console --language C# --name Socket --output Socket
>   --framework netcoreapp1.0

This created this project (which for some reason compiles to a dll despite the exe output type and console application target):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then manually modify the csproj file so it looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR" Version="1.0.6" />
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Now publish with:

> dotnet publish --runtime win7-x64 --configuration Release

And go to:

> ./bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/win7-x64

Now suddenly there is a working exe-file and just a few DLL files that is approximately 1 MB in size. By deleting the subfolder called "publish" I now have something that works without most of the bloat. No idea why this worked and if its considered expected behavior. No idea what the publish folder is for either or whether or not its needed for deployment on a computer without .NET installed. Microsoft have some work to do on its documentation.

Comment: Use .NET Framework and not .NET Core unless you want it to work cross-platform. Otherwise, just remove unused references within your project.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne I need cross-platform; is there any way to get the dotnet tool to discard or somehow identify which references are not actually needed? Sound a bit scary to just start deleting DLL's at random and hope everything works afterwards.

Comment: Use ReSharper. It's an **amazing** tool for tidying up code. It also identifies unused references/namespaces.

Comment: Is it not just the dependencies for kestrel which .net core uses?

Comment: This code should not depend on kestrel imho

Comment: Strange, I am targeting .NET Standard 1.2 and all I get is one DLL for my class library.

Comment: @gigi using visual studio 2017? Can you share your csconf? How do you build it?

Comment: @agnsaft Yes VS2017. The only difference I can see is that you seem to be targeting .NET Standard for what seems to be an executable application. That's kind of weird; AFAIK applications should target proper runtimes (e.g. .NET Framework or .NET Core), whereas class libraries may target .NET Standard or specific frameworks as required.

Comment: Actually, I targeted .NET core first but tried .Net standard to reduce dependencies. Same issue.

Comment: How did you get this project created? Use VS project template or `dotnet new`. What you pasted sounds invalid, as an exe project should not target .NET Standard.

Comment: I used the .net core console app template from visual studio 2017 and later changed it manually after hearing I could reduce dependencies by targeting .net standard. Needless to say it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index

In the 1st case, your `publish` command generates output for a `Framework-dependent deployment` that is relying on the presence of the .NET Core framework on the target machine. Your code (in the form of dll(s)) will be executed by the runtime.

In the 2nd case, when you specify the target runtime using the `--runtime` option, `publish` generates output for a `Self-contained deployment` in which the used version of the .NET Core framework is *included*. There's a way to reduce the total size of the output as described in the above mention article in the `Deploying a self-contained deployment with a smaller footprint`section.

As for why `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` didn't generate a `exe`-file, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-build

It basically says the generated

> binaries include the project's code in Intermediate Language (IL)
>   files with a .dll extension

and that the difference between specifying and not specifying `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`

> is that the IL DLL for a library doesn't contain entry points and
>   can't be executed.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer. Do you know why the portable build needs dlls almost 1 MB in size despite requiring .Net core installed, and why the self contained build comes with 200+ dlls (including those I dont use) and 50 MB size?

Comment: You're welcome! The portable, aka FDD, version should only include your own code and any non-.NET Core dependencies your app might have. In your example, there is none. In a throw-away folder, run `dotnet new console`, `dotnet restore` and then `dotnet build` and/or `dotnet publish`, and you should see just a small `dll` in the output folder (along with `json` and `pdb` files of insignificant sizes). In your project, try deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders and repeat the steps starting from `dotnet restore`.

Comment: As for SDD, you end up with many files because this type of deployment includes .NET Core itself. As pointed out in the article I mentioned, you could minimize the deployment's footprint by explicitly referencing the componponent of .NET Core that your app needs, in the `.csproj` file. I see you attempted doing it by referencing `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR` explicitly. But there's one other thing that needs to be done in `.csproj` -- change `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>netstandard1.6</TargetFramework>`.

Comment: What I dont really understand is why Microsoft insists on bundling library DLLs like "System.Xml" when its not used by the project and not defined as a dependency. I also dont quite understand the difference between "./bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/win7-x64/" and "./bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/win7-x64/publish/" after a publish (both has the application, but only publish has the entire .NET core bundled).

Comment: I guess the idea there is that it is expected that the whole .NET Core framework is available on the target machine. There could be reasons for that. One of them might be the fact that when you generate an SDD, the `.exe` file is not your program, but rather `a renamed version of the platform-specific .NET Core host` which might need more framework functionality than your app alone. `./bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/win7-x64/` contains the output of the `build` command, whereas `./bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/win7-x64/publish/` that of the `publish` command. Running `publish` generates both.